# What events and/or methods does the iOS video player expose?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, documentation, quicktime

I'm not an iOS developer, but I'm just trying to figure out whether it's possible to query the iOS native video player in a Cocoa Touch app at runtime, and say find out how much of the video has been played.

I also wondered whether the player exposes events, such as scrubbing, play start, play end, play pause etc.

Again, this is all for an Objective-c app, not a web app.

Not being an iOS developer, I had trouble trying to find this in Apple's documentation.

If anyone could point me to the appropriate article that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are trying to achieve should be possible with [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If something is missing, there is a lower level API called [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html).